# Laravel: Get form field error with form element name as key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to learn `laravel`. I know `Codeigniter`. In `codeigniter3` I will get the form error as an array with key as the form name by using the function

```
$this -> form_validation -> error_array();
```

it will display like

```
array(
    'form_element1' => 'this field is required',
    'form_element2' => 'this field is required'
)
```

**Is there any way in laravel 5 to do the same?**

Please help. Any help could be appreciated

Answer (score 13):

Laravel controller uses `ValidatesRequests` trait which provides a `validate` method. Here is example how to validate a request:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'subject' => 'required|max:255',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);

        // All input is valid, do your task.
    }

}
```

If user inputs doesn't pass the rules of `$this->validate()` it will be automatically redirect your user back to the form view with old input and errors. The errors is held by `$errors` variable which is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag`, to display it on your view:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="error">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Or you can get error by key:

```
@if($errors->has('subject'))
    {{ $errors->first('subject');}} // Printed: Subject field is required.
@endif
```

To answer your question about how to display errors like in CI you can use `toArray()` method of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag`:

```
$errors->toArray()
```

## Manual Validation

You may also use validator instance manually using the `Validator` facade, like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Validator;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'subject' => 'required|max:255',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('your-form-uri')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        // All input is valid, do your task.
    }

}
```

Again you can get the errors from `$errors` variable as above.

## Form Request Validation

To use this method, you can start by creating a form validation request using `artisan` CLI:

```
 php artisan make:request ContactRequest
```

It will create you a `ContactRequest` class, you can find it in `app/Http/Request/` folder.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ContactRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'subject' => 'required|max:225',
            'message' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

On your controller method variable instead of using `Request $request` you may use `ContactRequest $request`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function store(ContactRequest $request)
    {
        // All input is valid, do your task.
    }

}
```

If user input passes it will continue to execute your code on that method otherwise user will be redirected back to form view, and of course you can display the errors the same as two method above.

Answer (score 7):

you can set a return from controller

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($request->all());
```

or

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(Input::all());
```

and you can print errors in view as

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: I am already doing this. In this method, the array index are 1,2,... I need the form element name as array index/key

Comment: use with('key' => 'message')

Comment: @Laravel-user  Thanks, small typo
`return redirect->back()...`
should be
`return redirect()->back()...`

Answer (score 0):

This will display each error message attached to its key:

```
@foreach($errors->getMessages() as $key => $error)
    {{$key}}: {{$error[0]}}
@endforeach
```